# How do I embed a file from my computer in microsoft word so that after emailing the recipient can open that link?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I embed a file in my word document by choosing insert->object and then email the word document, the recipient is unable to open the embedded file.  How can I rectify this and send it all as one file and one package without using zip or some other packaging.

Comment: Does the file *have* to be in a Word doc? Could you not attach it directly to the email?

Comment: When you insert the file ensure that "link to file" (or similarly worded check box) is unchecked.

Comment: What type(s) of file are you trying to embed?